# Override template, layout custom module magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have custom module and custom theme and i need to override template and layout.Module magic

1. Override and edit in theme template from module Magic.
2. Change file template block in xml module.

My template DIR in module Magic/view/frontend/templates/sayhello.phtm and layuot Magic/view/frontend/layout magic_index_index.xml

How i can  to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create <Vendor_name>_Magic/layout in your theme  and copy magic_index_index.xml and paste it to the same created folder

and then the same go for a template